# NetBeans (7.3.1) detects false errors in C

Tags: c, netbeans, syntax, netbeans-7

I was trying to play with pointer syntax and I didn't get why I was getting some of the errors I've got. Then when I've tried to compile it with gcc it worked. Is there a way to fix this in NetBeans? It's really annoying to work with false errors...

[image]
The code in the picture is:

```
int (*(*f3(int z))(double ))(float ){
        return NULL;
}
```

This is broken as well yay! :

```
char (* ( *f())[])(){
    return NULL;
}
```

It seems that [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is better in parsing C that this IDE, embarrassing...

Comment: @bash.d Nah. This is a proper declaration of a function which returns a pointer to a function which returns a pointer to a function.

Comment: @bash.d It isn't: "when I've tried to compile it with gcc it worked."

Comment: @bash.d the compiler is not complaining as you can see, but the IDE does (NetBeans), that's the problem, and it's a dumb but legal declaration as I said a I was experimenting with pointer syntax...

Comment: What does NetBeans show when you put mouse pointer over the exclamation mark of the error in the line number border?

Comment: just go to the error line and press alt+Enter and show us the suggestions it gives for your error or show us the error line which is shown when you put mouse pointer over red error mark..

Comment: @JProgrammer It says Unexpected identifier: { , Unable to resolve identifier f3,Unable to resolve identifier z, etc basically it whines about almost everything (Unexpected return,} ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Netbeans, there's nothing you can do about it except for reporting it (or fixing it yourself). I think you can't even completely turn off these error indications in Netbeans.

Netbeans has a lot of bugs like this, and other IDEs like Eclipse and Code::Blocks are no better. Although I would think that parsing entered code is the single most important core functionality of an IDE that distinguishes it from an ordinary text editor, they fail surprisingly often when you write some more complicated constructs or use newer language features.

Comment: You're saying eclipse is not better because it's broken there too or you just expressed your frustration from similar problems?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have this exact problem, but I've encountered similar bugs in Eclipse (for example [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413204)). At least Eclipse lets you disable the different kinds of errors and warnings, so they don't annoy you until a bug that affects you is fixed.